# What does the type "Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()" mean?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a code snippet, which is looks as follows

```
displayAge :: Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()
displayAge maybeAge =
  case maybeAge of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid year"
    Just maybeAge -> putStrLn $ show maybeAge
```

This function takes its parameter from the console and is passed to it through `readMay` function as follows;

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Your birth year"
  strYear <- getLine
  let maybeAge = do
        intYear <- readMay strYear
        return (processYear intYear)
  displayAge maybeAge
```

Can you please explain the type declaration of the `displayAge` function. Why is `Show a` used?

Comment: The constraing `Show a` appears because you called the `show` function. It's that simple. (...`putStrLn $ show maybeAge`...)

Comment: BTW, `maybeAge` is more commonly defined as ``maybeAge = processYear `fmap` readMay strYear`` or ``maybeAge = processYear <$> readMay strYear``.

Answer (score 5):

`displayAge` takes a value that is `Maybe` of type `a`, where `a` is any type which can be `Show`n.

It's often useful to first read what's on the right-hand side of `=>` in Haskell signatures, i.e. `Maybe a -> IO ()`

Comment: In other words we can say that there is constraint on type a that it should be an instance of typeclass Show

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a type declaration, so it is going to tell you about what you need to supply to the function `displayAge` in order for the type checker to be happy.  The lines that follow actually describe how the function works.  Type declarations are (nearly always) optional, but they are important documentation, and frequently make error messages make a lot more sense because the compiler now knows what you thought you wanted to do and can compare that to what you actually did.

### `Show a`

The first part of the declaration, the piece before the `=>` tells us something about `a`. We note that `a` is lower case so it is *not* a type but a type variable.  When you actually use the `displayAge` function you may use any type you wish in place of `a` (Int, String, [Double], etc ...) but this says that there must be a `Show` instance for that type.  So just about any type that is not a function.  If classes in haskell are still confusing to you, check out [this section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) of [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) (really it is as good as _Why's tutorial on Ruby)

### `Maybe a`

There are lots of ways to read Haskell type signatures, but if your new, it can help to think of all the types before the last arrow (`->`) as "inputs" and the final type as "output." This idea misses currying, and first class functions, but it can really help get you started.

So this function wants a `Maybe a` and will give you an `IO()`.

What then is a `Maybe a`?  If you are not familiar with the `Maybe` type you should certainly make an effort to become so.  It is a second order type.  That means that in order to use it you need to give it some other type to contain. Maybe holds some other type.  So `Maybe Int` holds and `Int`, and `Maybe String` holds a `String`.  But this function is designed to work with a `Maybe` which holds any type at all (so long has it has a Show instance like we noted above). Again note that lower case `a` If this function had needed some type in particular, it would have used a type that started with a Capital letter.

### `IO()`

Ok, this could be the hard part. This function rather then calculating some new value, does something to the Real World -- All the things that exist beyond the world of haskell is the Real World. So user input and output, network stuff and mutable memory all have to go inside an IO type. (Yes it is second order just like Maybe) This is the famous and lovely IO monad which we hope you have heard of, and will learn to love.  When a function comes with the type `IO()` it means that it *does* something rather then returning a value.  In our case we think it should probably display and age, right?. You will need to use `displayAge` in a `do` block like the one for the `main` function*.

---

* Not strictly true, you can use bind (`>>=`) instead, but come on this is clearly a beginners question, and we have this rule about not writing monad tutorials, right?